# Passing a parameter to npm start from mocha

Tags: node.js

I have written test cases for my nodejs application using mocha and supertest. But my nodejs application is having an argument to start development environment and production environment as e.g, npm start -- development, npm start -- production. But from my mocha & supertest  application ,how can i start  the server for two different environments. I am giving as below

```
var server = supertest.agent("https://XXXXXX:3050")
```

so how can i cover test case fro both the environments

Comment: What is the `npm start` command?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just pass in additional arguments and use `process.argv` from the file invoked by the `npm start` command. This will return an array that you can then take the index of the argument, i.e. `process.argv[indexOfArgument]`.

Or, in the case you've specified, you may want to use environment variables, i.e. `$ NODE_ENV=development npm start`, and then in your respective files something like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // do something
}
```